# Ruby on Rails tutorial Chapter 11: Rspec tests fail on follower/following section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm working on [Chapter 11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top) of Hartl's tutorial, trying to get the `non-logged-in users in the Users controller visiting the followers and following page` to pass. I'm running into an error where Rails would complain about an undefined `admin?` method despite it being only used in a `User` partial.

**Rails local server**

```
Rendered users/_user.html.erb (9.4ms)
Rendered users/show_follow.html.erb within layouts/application (33.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <li>
    2:   <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
    3:   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    4:   <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    5:     | <%= link_to 'delete', user, method: :delete,
    6:                                   data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    7:   <% end %>
  app/views/users/_user.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users__user_html_erb___4000670281664801561_70099451578240'
  app/views/users/show_follow.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_users_show_follow_html_erb__2024448610717183111_70099484108000'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:68:in `followers'
```

**RSpec failures**

```
 1) Authentication authorization for non-logged-in users in the Users controller visiting the following page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
       expected css "title" with text "Login" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:122:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization for non-logged-in users in the Users controller visiting the followers page
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
       expected css "title" with text "Login" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:127:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**authorization_pages_spec.rb**

```
  describe "authorization" do
    .
    .
    .
    describe "for non-logged-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      .
      .
      .
      describe "in the Users controller" do
        .
        .
        .
        describe "visiting the following page" do
          before { visit following_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
        end

        describe "visiting the followers page" do
          before { visit followers_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Login') }
        end
      end
```

**show_follow.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
      <span><b>Posts:</b> <%= @user.posts.count %></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      <% if @users.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
          <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @users.any? %>
      <ul class="users">
        <%= render @users %>
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_user.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to 'delete', user, method: :delete, 
                                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

I tried copy and pasting all the problematic files from the tutorial itself to no avail. It's mentioned that by assigning the `:admin` attribute to the `User` class, a method `admin?` is made available to use. I'm guessing it's somehow I'm passing a `nil` object into the partials, but I'm having trouble debugging where exactly that's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out.

I forgot to put the `:following` and `:followers` actions in the `before_filter` for `:logged_in_user` in the User controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :logged_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
```

That took a while.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is checking `current_user.admin?` and changing what is displayed based on that. However from the title of your specs it appears that you are testing the behaviour when a non logged in user visits the page: current_user will be nil

Sounds like the if statement in the _user partial needs an extra condition to check that there is a logged in user before checking that that user is an admin

Comment: Right, I figured I could write a helper function to determine if a User object is hitting that page at all, but that part's missing in the tutorial, and I'm trying to figure out how Hartl got it to work without this intermediate step.

Comment: All you need to do is check if current_user is nil

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in the `users_controller`, your code in the partials looks okay to me which means it's possibly something behind the scenes that is missing. The local server trace seems to point to line 68 and the followers method. Mine looks like this, fyi:

```
def followers 
   @title = "Followers"
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
   render 'show_follow'
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looking at Frederick's question above actually - when you run the local server, is the page displaying correctly, or is it just your tests that are failing?

Comment: I posted the error I get from the local server when I try to visit a page like `/users/1/following`. For some users it'd work, for others it wouldn't. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

I also forgot to put the :following and :followers actions in the before_filter for :logged_in_user in the User controller, but I was curious about this error.

Like Frederick Cheung points in is response there is bug in the code of the parcial: _user.html.erb.  We should check if current_user is nil before calling the admin? method on it.

So instead of:

```
 <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
```

you should have:

```
 <% if current_user && current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
```

This removes the "undefined method admin?" error and gives us the correct test error:

```
 Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

This last one we remove by putting the :following and :followers actions in the before_filter for :logged_in_user.